Filament filters not updating data with Sushi model
I have a filament app with a resource which is loading data from an API using Sushi
This is the resource:
class PersonResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Person::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-rectangle-stack';
    public static ?string $slug = 'people';

    protected $listeners = [
        'filtered' => '$refresh'
    ];    

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                //
            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        //Person::setVar('groupid1');      
        
        return $table
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('name')->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('email')->copyable()->searchable(),
            ])
            ->filters([            
                SelectFilter::make('Group')
                ->options([
                    '' => 'Please choose',
                    'groupid1' => 'Group 1',
                    'groupid2' => 'Group 2'
                ])

                ->query(function (Builder $query, array $data, $livewire): Builder {
                    Log::info("filter: ".$data['value']);                                 
                    self::$model::setVar($data['value']);                            
                    $livewire->dispatch('filtered');
                    return $query;
                })                
                ->default('')
                ->selectablePlaceholder(false)                
                
            ])
            ->deferLoading(false)
            ->actions([
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    ExportBulkAction::make()
                ]),                
            ]);
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ManagePeople::route('/'),
        ];
    }  
}


And this is the model:
class Person extends Model
{
    use Sushi;

    protected static $id;

    public static function setVar($id)
    {
        Log::info("set new id: ".$id);
        self::$id = $id;
        return self::query();
    }  

    /**
     * Model Rows
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function getRows()
    {
        $graph = new Graph();
        $graph->setAccessToken('xxx');
        if(self::$id == null) return [];    
   
        Log::info("load: ".self::$id);
        $people = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/groups/'.self::$id.'/members?$top=999')->setReturnType(Person::class)->execute();      
        $people_array = [];
        foreach($people as $person) {
            $people_array[] = ['name' => $person->Name(), 'email' => $person->getMail()];
        }  
        
        return $people_array;
    } 
    
    protected function sushiShouldCache()
    {
        return false;
    }    
    
}

If I set the models $id at the beginning of the table(Table $table) function it loads the data. Also the filter works and sets the new $id but the model is still loading data with the old $id.
How can I reload the resource with the new $id? How to access the right model instance?
I have around 40 groups and I don't want to create a resource and model for each group, there must be some generic way, hopefully ...
